# how to fix Jest encountered an unexpected token React

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, babel-jest

I m trying to run a react app, created using `create-react-app`. App runs successfully, but when I try to run JEST it give me the following error. I have looked and tried various options but could not fix it. Here is my package.json and jest.config.json

please suggest on what I might be doing wrong

Thank you
A

Error

```
 FAIL  src/App.test.js
```

● Test suite failed to run

```
Jest encountered an unexpected token

This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".

Here's what you can do:
 • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
 • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
 • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html

Details:

SyntaxError: C:\Test\counter-app\src\App.test.js: Unexpected token (7:18)

   5 | it('renders without crashing', () => {
   6 |   const div = document.createElement('div');
>  7 |   ReactDOM.render(<App />, div);
     |                   ^
   8 |   ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(div);
   9 | });
```

package.json

```
    {
  "name": "counter-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "jest": {
    "verbose": true,
    "moduleDirectories": ["node_modules", "src"],
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!(react-native|react-native-cookies)/)"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "react": "^16.11.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.11.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.2.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "jest --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

jest.config.js

```
const {defaults} = require('jest-config');
module.exports = {
  "verbose": true,
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest",
    "^.+\\.(css|scss|less)$": "jest-css-modules",
    ".+\\.(css|styl|less|sass|scss)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/jest-css-modules-transform"
  },
  "globals": {
    "NODE_ENV": "test"
  },
  moduleFileExtensions: [...defaults.moduleFileExtensions, 'js', 'jsx'],
  "moduleDirectories": [
    "node_modules",
    "src/frontend",
    "src/shared"
  ]
};
```

Comment: Maybe try this solution found on github: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/6933#issuecomment-538317442

Answer (score 0):

Modified Package.json as follows:

```
{
  "name": "foo",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "jest-junit": "^9.0.0",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.2.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "reporters": [ "default", "jest-junit" ],
    "test": "react-scripts test --watchAll=false",
    "testResultsProcessor": "jest-junit",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "jest-junit": {
    "suiteName": "jest tests",
    "outputDirectory": ".",
    "outputName": "junit.xml",
    "uniqueOutputName": "false",
    "classNameTemplate": "{classname}-{hello}",
    "titleTemplate": "{classname}-{helloTests}",
    "ancestorSeparator": " › ",
    "usePathForSuiteName": "true"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing jest.config.js file completely and let it work with default config.